# extract values from txt

Tags: php, strpos

Hi i have a txt file on a web server of a solar inverter. 
This is an example of the file sys.txt:  **master#0.75kW#24.9#404.1#2630.5#42715.4#0#0#1;0;0.33;9.4;15555.6;132;1#2;0;0.15;6.0;11168.7;2097185;3#3;0;0.27;9.4;15991.0;2097185;3#x#**

I need the 1°,2°,5° numeric value that is between #  ( in this case 0.75 24.9 42715.4 ) that are actual power, daily power and total power. I tried to write a php script but I can't finish it properly..

```
/* ########## DATA SUNWAYS ########## */
    $url = “13.3.89.50/data/sys.txt”;
    $username = “customer”;
    $password = “00000000”;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $actualpower = strpos($output,'/\#(.#?)\#/');   //?????
    $dailypower = strpos($output,'/\#(.#?)\#/');    //?????
    $totalpower = substr($output,'/\#(.#?)\#/' );   //?????
```

can you help me?

Comment: What about exploding on `#`? `Strpos` and `substr` don't work with regexs.

Comment: You're looking for `preg_match` preferrably. And here's a proper → `"` ← double quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `explode()` function to separate the differents value by `#`, then apply `filter_var()` to extract only numeric values.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

So this should achieve your needs:

```
$input = 'master#0.75kW#24.9#404.1#2630.5#42715.4#0#0#1;0;0.33;9.4;15555.6;132;1#2;0;0.15;6.0;11168.7;2097185;3#3;0;0.27;9.4;15991.0;2097185;3#x#';
$inputArray = explode('#', $input); // get an array with all the separate values

// keep only numeric on the 2nd field (index 1)
$actualPower = filter_var($inputArray[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$dailyPower = filter_var($inputArray[2],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$totalPower = filter_var($inputArray[5],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);

echo $actualPower . ' ' . $dailyPower . ' '. $totalPower;
```

Will print

> 0.75 24.9 42715.4

Comment: thank you but the txt file changes every second.. I tried with above code but doesn't work at all.. :/

Comment: yes, the inverter changes every second the values between ##. there is a second part of the script, where i send actual power, daily and total to a virtual counter in domoticz

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
<?php
$login = 'customer';
$password = '00000000';
$url = 'http://13.3.89.50/data/sys.txt';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$results = explode('#', $result);

$actualPower = filter_var($results[1],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$dailyPower = filter_var($results[2],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$totalPower = filter_var($results[5],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
?>
```